# List drives API giving resource not founf

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

A simple get drives API

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives
```

In graph explorer is returning

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "3064cf71-b4d0-4f3c-bd46-0a87cb447af2",
            "date": "2018-06-12T03:42:16"
        }
    }
}
```

Has this been remvoved? How can I get all drives of a user

Comment: the size of the list is very large, it is not allowing me to delete, remove any folder or document library, What should I do?

Comment: opening link gives Sorry, something went wrong
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904
TECHNICAL DETAILS



Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
Correlation ID: 0348709e-7014-5000-faaa-6e027771b04b

Date and Time: 6/11/2018 9:49:00 PM

Comment: **Site has become totally inaccessible** . Please can someone help in bring the site http://bluejdemo.sharepoint.com **up** again.  URGENT

Comment: Get [support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/contact-support-for-business-products-admin-help-32a17ca7-6fa0-4870-8a8d-e25ba4ccfd4b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) if you are still experiencing this issue.